# Fragment overlapping on click event ? - ANDROID

Tags: android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

I don't know why my application behave in 2 different ways when i'm changing fragments. I have a menu drawer and inside a fragment i try to launch a new fragment on the same container using click event.
so when i use the menu to access to that fragment everything work well but when i try to access to the same fragment from another fragment (same container) i got on my screen both fragment overlapping.

[Home fragment image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Vq4.png)

as you can see in this fragment i try to click on the bank icon to change the current fragment with another and that the result 
[fragment overlapping image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSadQ.png)

i'm using the fragment class to execute the click event here is the code :

```
cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new AboutFragment());
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
```

Please remember that when i access to the 2nd fragment using menu it works.

Comment: are you sure the ID you are providing in `replace()` is the ID of your Fragment container and not the fragment?

Comment: @Sam. Yes i'm sure